# Exporting Large Data Sets

Tags: export, filemaker

I work for a mid sized online fashion company, and we have a very large report that we export with an FM Server side script, approx 75 fields/15k records.

The problem I have, is as you imagine - this takes an awful long time! We have a lot of calculation fields, perform finds, replaces etc in the script before the export, in order to build and update the report each day with new data, I should also state that there is a lot of related data from other tables in the export.

I'm acutely aware that this won't be a fast export, however if anyone has any tips on how to minimise export time I would be most grateful. At present we are exporting as CSV, so for example would XLSX be quicker?

Any advice at all on how to speed this up would be most welcome!

Thankyou - 
S

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a generic question, probably better suited for a FileMaker users forum.

15k is not that many records even for FileMaker.

CSV will be quicker then Excel export, but I do not think this is your problem

Try to break you export into stages and log the time spent on every stage. This will show what stage you need to optimise.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the reason for the slow export is the related fields and any unstored calculations you are exporting. You can get around this by using cached fields, non-related, non-calculated fields, that get updated just before the export with various `Replace Field Contents` script steps performed on the server.

Separate the script into three scripts, `Find Records to Export`, `Update Caches`, and `Export Report`. They would look something like this:

## `Find Records to Export`

```
Go to Layout [ "LayoutWithFieldsToReplace" ]
Enter Find Mode [ Pause: Off ]
Set Field [ TABLE::field ; // find criterion for this field ]
Set Field [ ...
Set Error Capture [ On ]
Perform Find []
```

## `Update Caches`

```
Perform Script [ Find Records to Export ]
Replace Field Contents [ TABLE::cache_1 ; RELATED::field ]
Replace Field Contents [ TABLE::cache_2 ; TABLE::unstored_calc ]
Replace Field Contents [ ...
```

## `Export Report`

```
Perform Script on Server [ Update Caches ]
Perform Script [ Find Records to Export ]
Export Records [ ...
```

I'm not sure if FileMaker has changed to requirement, but I *think* the fields you need to replace the contents of need to be on the layout during the replace. So make sure the layout you navigate to has them, in the script above, these would be `TABLE::cache_1` and `TABLE::cache_2`.